# Android extract time of calls from call log

Tags: android, calllog

I am looping through the call log and saving the dates of the calls into an array. During this process, I get dates like 1315164925580.
Part of the call log loop:

```
int dateColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
long callDate = c.getLong(dateColumn);
```

I can turn this long into a date:

```
SimpleDateFormat datePattern = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
Long datelong = Long.parseLong("1315164925580");
String date_str = datePattern.format(new Date(datelong));
```

Results: 2011-09-04

How can I extract the time of calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28%29) method instead of SimpleDateFormat and if neaded specify output format in get method.

```
DateFormat datePattern = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM);
Long datelong = Long.parseLong("1315164925580");
String date_str = datePattern.format(datelong);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `SimpleDateFormat` format string: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your `SimpleDateFormat` format string (in constructor) to include time parameters such as: `"hh:mm a"`